# how to load a local file in using an html document

Tags: html, file

Is there any way to load a local file using an html document that lives on my HD?
I was thinking of making an html-based overview page of a project that I'm working on, but I can't seem to find a way to get the browser to open my text based files in the native application that they are bound to (for ex., TextWrangler or whatnot).  Does anyone have experience with this?

It seems that the browser is by design, only allowed to handle files inline.

Comment: Please add some code if you have, i couldn't quite get what you mean by Loading ?

Comment: something like an <a> tag, but that loads a file with the os's defined target application.

Comment: so you don't want the file to be downloaded but to be shown in your html page ?

Comment: the original question mentions that i would like to load a local file, not that i would like to download anything.  basically i want a browser to launch a file that is already on my HD.

Comment: It is totally possible but this question is not clear enough to know how to answer it. One possibility is the file:// protocol. Another possibility is to execute a server, such as IIS (I use IIS) or Apache, locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely by design.  You don't want the browser to have direct execution access to local files on your machine for security reasons.

Comment: i realize this, but the file will only be used locally.  it's for a project, not for a system.  but yeah; i understand the serurity issues involved.

Comment: You may open html-files in normal browsers, and execute javascript, which is contained in them; or Java Applets. Since it is '''your''' file, it is your responsibility not to do evil things.

Comment: I can do it. The only reason you think it is not possible is because you don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on Windows using ActiveX.  There is a simple example at http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/51/45/ and more elaborate schemes are possible.  But ActiveX is not cross platform, and I doubt it is possible to do similar on proper secure operating systems.

Update: Here is a possible way to configure Firefox to do it on any operating system, but this would only really work for your own personal use:
[How open a local file with the associated program from a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393427/how-open-a-local-file-with-the-associated-program-from-a-web-page/2393501#2393501)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script, which wraps your filenames (+ xyz-info) into a html-template.

Comment: huh.  how do html templates help in this case?  i want the file to be called up, as in the open command we see in a terminal or similar.

Comment: could you also point me to some links that might have some information on what your proposed methodology would look like?  thanks

Comment: (I'm sorry for answering that late - had connection/account-problems.) I wasn't sure what the main interest of your question is - triggering via html, generating overview-html, opening the file with a special app or what. And I don't know how close BSD and Linux are, maybe close, maybe not. I once had a link in a local html-page, which I use as a kind of enhanced bookmark-page (but manually created and maintained). One Link on this page is http://192.168.32.3:64064/start, the webaddress of the machine itself. This calls a service on port 64064 - the number is mostly random. (...)

Comment: It should be higher than 1000, because lower ports are privileged, but not much higher than 65000 - else it exceeds the valid range.

Comment: ... higher than 65535 - else it exceeds the valid range. Then you need a service running, named inetd - maybe renamed today to xinetd and portmapper. In /etc/inetd.conf you need a line: `webstart        stream  tcp     nowait  root    /home/YOURNAME/bin/webstart` The name `webstart` can be changed, but needs to be changed everywhere. In /home/YOURNAME/etc/services: `webstart 64064/tcp   # Test to start a service via a webpage`. I used this 5 or more years ago, and just for testing. Maybe I've forgot a step, and it might be outdated today, and not work on BSD. Look for manpages inetd/xinetd.

Comment: could you maybe post a link that describes how this relates to my original question?

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question. It isn't clear at all what you want. A local file in firefox can be loaded with `file:///opt/sample.html` in the browsers adressbar. To open it from a html-File, you put the usual 'a'-Tag around: '<a href="file:///opt/sample.html> sample </a>'. Now the question is, how that is related to your project-text-file(s).

Answer (score 0):

While you can refer to local files as file://users/me/Documents/stuff.txt its unlikely a user will have files where a remote server might expect. As well as the security implications of doing such a thing.

Comment: i have a script that finds where the current dir is and can look up files inside of a directory that is supposed to be present.  if the directory is not present, the script fails, which is fine.  referring to the local files via file://x/x/x/  doesn't seem to work, as a given browser seems to try to load the file inline.  i'm assuming you are talking about an <a> tag, no?

Comment: The details of how to use something like file://x/x/x/ varies for the various browsers but it should work somehow. This apparently is not a programming question so it should not be in Stackoverflow. In the future anyone looking for answers should look in a different forum ([Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com))?: