# Open a Internet explorer/Firefox etc window with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm building a smaller Web Builder with Javascript and I want the user to be available to preview their page in all the major browsers. Because that the tool only is available for Chrome I need them to get the chance to open a Internet explorer window with the same information, and the same for Firefox and Opera and Safari... Is there a way to do so, in Javascript?

P.S. The information that should appear on in the window is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If JS can call `firefox.exe`, it could also call `nasty_trojan.exe`.  The best you can do is generate a custom link server-side, and say "paste this link into your other browsers.

Unless you'd like to be really fancy, in which case you need to render the pages server-side, ala http://browsershots.org/.

There's a chance it could be done if you wrote it as a chrome extension, because those have some measure of trust, but the JS on a page stays very much inside its sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't belong on the answers, but I did not see how to comment (I am new, sorry!). [This may help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393427/how-open-a-local-file-with-the-associated-program-from-a-web-page) It seems you may need to use a java applet, at least, I'm seeing that in a few places. Hope I've helped!

Comment: You need 50 reputation for the "comment anywhere" privilege: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment